# Select case not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have this very simple case in my select statement

```
   CASE WHEN PHONENR IS NOT NULL THEN '+46'+PHONENR ELSE ' ' END AS Phone
```

my issue here i get to add the country code nr correctly infront of all existing numbers, but the empty rows are getting a default value of +46 instead of being just empty

Comment: Are you sure those are `NULL` and not `` (empty string)? Also, is `+45` a typo?

Comment: Do you really want to use `" "`(so a space) if the `PHONENR` is empty or `NULL`?

Comment: Don't use empty strings when no phone number, use NULL!

Comment: Generally I would agree, use `NULL` instead of an empty string. However, I often get requirements which stipulate a space when source is `NULL`. So I wouldn't make it into a law...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190329.aspx) instead

```
CASE WHEN LEN(PHONENR)>1 THEN ....
```

Comment: @MishMish Out of curiosity, what is the result of `SELECT ASCII(PHONENR) FROM ..` for one of your "empty rows"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
CASE WHEN PHONENR <> '' THEN '+46'+PHONENR ELSE ' ' END AS Phone
```

The first branch is only entered if PHONENR is not null or empty string.

Comment: I have already tried this one, unfortinatly i still get +46 where it supposed to be empty, yet your methode still works on others case examples

Comment: would it be because phone nr is registered as varchar type in the db?

Comment: This works even if `PHONENR` is `"     "` since `'' = '    '`(ignores spaces)

Comment: @MishMish - This works fine, you must have tried something different. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb354/1) - Or the "empty strings" in fact are tabs or some other non printing character.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking for values have something besides a space and adding the country code to those values.  Something like this:

```
(case when phonenr like '%[^ ]%' then '+46' + PHONENR 
      else ''
 end)
```

That is, if the phone number contains a non-space character, then append the country code.

You could even take this a step further, and append the country code only when the phone number has at least one digit:

```
(case when phonenr like '%[0-9]%' then '+46' + PHONENR 
      else ''
 end)
```

Let me go a step further.  You can use `check` constraints to validate the data when it is put into the database.  I would suggest a check constraint that validates the structure of the phone number -- say, it only contains a set of characters or a `NULL` value:

```
alter table add constraint chk_phonenr check (phonenr not like '%[^-0-9()+ ]%' and phonenr like '%[0-9]%')
```

This would ensure that the field has reasonable values or `NULL`.  If you had this constraint, your original query would work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try this one as well! :-)